# CPLEX/DOCPLEX Run Time Problem on Apple Silicon

Tags: cplex, docplex

I installed CPLEX Studio 22.1 on my Apple Macbook (M2 CPU).
Almost everything seems to be fine:

- I can call `cplex` and `cpoptimizer` interactives from `/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx/cplex` and `/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cpoptimizer/bin/x86-64_osx/cpoptimizer`, and can also optimize some examples of mp/cp successfully.
- I installed python packages: `cplex` and `docplex` via the commmand

```
python /Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/python/setup.py install
```

and it seems to be fine also.

- I tested the system with the command
  `python -m docplex.cp.check_list`
  and got the following:

```
Execution environment:
 * System: Darwin, 64bit
 * Python version: 3.10.6, 64 bits (/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python)
 * Docplex version: 2.23.221
 * Optional packages: numpy: 1.23.2, panda: None, matplotlib: 3.5.3
 * Solver agent: local, executable file: '/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cpoptimizer/bin/x86-64_osx/cpoptimizer'
 * Solver version: 22.1.0.0
No problem found.
```

- **HOWEVER**, when I tried with `python -m docplex.mp.check_list`, I got

```
* system is: Darwin 64bit
* Python version 3.10.6, located at: /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python
* docplex is present, version is 2.23.221
* CPLEX library is not available
* pandas is present, version is 1.4.3
Cplex runtime not found, error importing cplex: dlopen(/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cplex-22.1.0.0-py3.10.egg/cplex/_internal/py310_cplex2210.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cplex-22.1.0.0-py3.10.egg/cplex/_internal/py310_cplex2210.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))

* diagnostics: 1
  -- No local installation of CPLEX has been found.
```

As far as I know, the `docplex.cp.model` works here, but `docplex.mp.model` failed since the local cplex not found on the system.
The variable `PYTHONPATH` has been set to `/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx/`.
I have no ideas what I missed to configure on the installation process.

Moreover, I still get a minor problem when trying to run `oplide`. It can not be executed, but `oplrun` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are with a Mx Apple cpu, I bet the python you run is running in arm64 mode which will fail at loading the intel based CPLEX libraries.
You should try to run it with '''arch -x86_64 python'''

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I tried with`arch -x86_64 python -m docplex.mp.check_list`, but still got the same result.